# iPad not accepting Apple ID

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-id, password

For some time now my iPad Air 2 has been pestering me to enter my Apple ID. When I do, I get error "Verification Failed Your Apple ID or password is incorrect". I'm currently using my MacBook with the same Apple ID without any problems.

After searching the inertnet I've

- tried rebooting the device without help
- changed my Apple ID password twice without help
- updated to iOS 14.3, still no help

One advice is trying to sign in using another account - but the bloody thing doesn't even allow me to sign out!!! It's asking me to enter Apple ID password to turn off "Find My iPad", which then subsequently fails.

I've tried with multiple wireless connections. Currently iPad's associated with my phone's hotspot with 4G connection, and Speedtest gives consistently ~85Mbps down / ~40Mbps up, so at least speed shouldn't be an issue. According to https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/ all services are available.

Last thing I tried was resetting iPad's network settings. After restarting I connected to my hotspot successfully and tried to login, which resulted in my account getting locked. I successfully unlocked it with my MacBook. However, still not able to login with my iPad.

How do I get this pesky thing working?

UPDATE

Tried to erase and reset the entire iPad. This also failed, as it requires entering the Apple ID.

Comment: this is an obvious question so pardon me but is your capslock key on your ipad set to on?

Comment: Not at all. It's not :-)

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below.

Comment: Thx mate, will do

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by yet another time changing my Apple ID password.